# How can I transfer a DigitalOcean droplet to another host

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, file-transfer

I would like to switch to a different VPS host. How would I transfer a DigitalOcean droplet to another host?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pain. I use DigitalOcean, AWS, Google Cloud, and Vultr. It's hypothetically possible, mad the best explanation is [here](https://vpsranked.com/quickly-migrate-vps-servers-between-digitalocean-vultr-and-lunanode/); however, as they point out, while it may be difficult for servers that have been active for a very long time, a fresh start is at least worthy of consideration, given the incompatibility of the file formats big cloud services use for snapshots.

Also, keep in mind that even if you can get the snapshot to boot on AWS or Azure or wherever you're going, it's likely the virtual network configuration will be totally different. You're going to be stuck doing network configuration and possibly new reverse proxies and the like. Probably only accessible through the slow browser shell your new provider offers. Do not recommend, from experience.